# How to create a simple 'Hello World' with two language in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, multilingual

i have been searching for easy sample of multi language project in `cakephp`.
but i can't find this sample. i think should use `i18n` but i can't use.
can help me for this sample?

Comment: yes this link is useful but i can't create this project too

Comment: Read my article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/kicaj/2013/01/27/internationalization_with_static_and_dynamic_content_routing_and_switching. Yes I know, my english is disgusting

Comment: Why can't you use i18n?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you've to combine the link that Matt gave you, which is the way to use translation on static texts on your website for ex. like links "More..." etc, with Translate behavior, which as mentioned before is based of i18n and will give you the possibility to use Translation on your models stored in DB.

Please check this page in book: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Behaviors/Translate.html hope this will be helpfull

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a controller in app>controllers> (create the controller here)
Then you need to declare an action in the controller.
For example in the examples_controllers.php controller file:

`ExamplesController extends AppController{
    function anyName() { 
        var $uses = null;
       $this->set('hello', "hello world");
      }
   }`

to call this from view:

create a folder under views (make sure give the name same as the controller name)
For above controller, the folder name will be examples.
Then in the folder, create "any_Name.ctp" file. (the name should be as the action name)
In that ctp file just call that variable hello. That will do.

I surfed through the web and got a complete solution in here, on my site:
http://www.getallthing.com/cake-php-hello-world/

Best of luck! Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.